# How to show days in a week without specific date in Vuetify v-calendar in weekly mode?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In Vuetify [v-calendar weekly mode example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars#weekly) the header shows day name (eg. Mon or Monday) and day of the month (eg. 7th of the month). Is it possible to show only day names without month days? I'd like to use this control just as a weekly schedule and without coupling it to the specific date or week in a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source of [vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/VCalendarDaily.ts) (line 98 - line 121) you can't override this behavior, but you can't hide the date itself with css:

```
.v-calendar-daily_head-day-label {
    display: none;
}
```

If you use the scoped styling don't forgot to use the deep selector

Answer (score 0):

The above answer in now outdated.

With the latest version of Vuetify (2.3.10) you can come close to hiding the date via slots as follows;

```
<v-sheet height="600">
  <v-calendar
  ref="calendar"
  type="week">
    <template v-slot:day-label-header="{}">-</template>
  </v-calendar>
</v-sheet>
```

Although it will show a "-" in place of the date if you use the above code.

Comment: Instead of "-", just place a empty string inside: `{{ " " }}`